# Como salvar retorno de requests e salvar em arquivo .txt ou .csv em Python

Tags: python, csv, txt, request

Gostaria de saber se é possível salvar o retorno de um request em arquivo .txt ou .csv em Python. Eu preciso de alguns dados do NIST e, para isso, fiz o seguinte código:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import lxml
    arquivo = open('file14.txt', 'w')
    req = requests.get('https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z14.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    lista = soup.find_all('pre')
    print(lista)
```

Com esse código eu faço a request e já separo o que eu preciso via Beautiful Soup. A resposta que eu espero vem na seguinte lista:

[

```
____________________________________
```

```
 <b>Energy</b>       <i>μ</i>/<i>ρ</i>        <i>μ</i><sub>en</sub>/<i>ρ</i> 

 <sup> </sup>(MeV)      (cm<sup>2</sup>/g)     (cm<sup>2</sup>/g)
```

---

1.00000E-03  1.570E+03  1.567E+03

1.50000E-03  5.355E+02  5.331E+02

1.83890E-03  3.092E+02  3.070E+02

K  1.83890E-03  3.192E+03  3.059E+03

2.00000E-03  2.777E+03  2.669E+03

3.00000E-03  9.784E+02  9.516E+02

4.00000E-03  4.529E+02  4.427E+02

5.00000E-03  2.450E+02  2.400E+02

6.00000E-03  1.470E+02  1.439E+02

8.00000E-03  6.468E+01  6.313E+01

1.00000E-02  3.389E+01  3.289E+01

1.50000E-02  1.034E+01  9.794E+00

2.00000E-02  4.464E+00  4.076E+00

3.00000E-02  1.436E+00  1.164E+00

4.00000E-02  7.012E-01  4.782E-01

5.00000E-02  4.385E-01  2.430E-01

6.00000E-02  3.207E-01  1.434E-01

8.00000E-02  2.228E-01  6.896E-02

1.00000E-01  1.835E-01  4.513E-02

1.50000E-01  1.448E-01  3.086E-02

2.00000E-01  1.275E-01  2.905E-02

3.00000E-01  1.082E-01  2.932E-02

4.00000E-01  9.614E-02  2.968E-02

5.00000E-01  8.748E-02  2.971E-02

6.00000E-01  8.077E-02  2.951E-02

8.00000E-01  7.082E-02  2.875E-02

1.00000E+00  6.361E-02  2.778E-02

1.25000E+00  5.688E-02  2.652E-02

1.50000E+00  5.183E-02  2.535E-02

2.00000E+00  4.480E-02  2.345E-02

3.00000E+00  3.678E-02  2.101E-02

4.00000E+00  3.240E-02  1.963E-02

5.00000E+00  2.967E-02  1.878E-02

6.00000E+00  2.788E-02  1.827E-02

8.00000E+00  2.574E-02  1.773E-02

1.00000E+01  2.462E-02  1.753E-02

1.50000E+01  2.352E-02  1.746E-02

2.00000E+01  2.338E-02  1.757E-02

]

Eu preciso salvar esses dados em um arquivo .txt ou .csv, de preferência .txt. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: este será um trabalho repetitivo? Caso não, porque vc simplesmente não copia e cola do próprio site? Caso positivo, vc terá que tratar o texto antes de salvá-lo para que fique em um formato adequado. Dê uma olhada na library [rows](https://github.com/turicas/rows). O intuito desta é extrair qualquer tabela de qualquer formato. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Se deseja salvar o arquivo exatamente como está na lista:

```
import io
with io.open('arquivo.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(str(lista))
```